# How can I make the avatar appear in large format?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
 
module.exports = {
    name: 'avatar',
    description: 'returns a users avatar',
    execute(message, args){
        const { prefix, token } = require ('../config.json');
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 
        if(!message.mentions.users.first()){
            embed.setTitle(`:camera_with_flash:Avatar de: @${user.username}`)
            embed.setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())
            embed.setDescription(`Clique aqui para baixar o avatar.`)
            embed.setColor('fffff1')
            embed.setFooter(".")
            return message.channel.send(embed)
        }else{
            const user = message.mentions.users.first()
            embed.setTitle(`:camera_with_flash:Avatar de: @${user.username}`)
            embed.setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL())
            embed.setDescription(`Clique aqui para baixar o avatar.`)
            embed.setColor('fffff1')
            embed.setFooter(".")
            return message.channel.send(embed)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to all this, sorry for my stupidity :c
is my first discord bot!
when I give the command !avatar on discord, the avatar comes out very small on the right of the embed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thumbnails are small. You would need to place the avatar in `.setImage()` then have it set to scale up to `256` in size

```
.setImage(user.avatarURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: false, size: 256 }))
```

This will ensure the image reaches a big size. Just keep in mind that some avatars might be low resolution, and can seem over blown if at a larger size.